# execute python script in interactive subshell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, python

I have a python script that needs to be run in an interactive shell (it monitors for certain cancel key input events, which i dont need).
I want to execute this script in the background, grab its output, then kill it after 5 seconds.

```
gnome-terminal -- "./script.sh > log.log"
```

or
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./script.sh > log.log"

doesnt work, because it's not an interactive shell...

I am using a standard ubuntu 1804 setup. How can i execute this script in an input-enabled terminal?

Answer (score 3):

I believe using the `subprocess` library will help in what you want to do.

Here's an example (according to the question):

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

command = shlex.split("<your command to run the script>")
process = subprocess.Popen(command)

try:
    outs, errs = process.communicate(timeout=5)

except TimeoutExpired:
    process.kill()
    outs, errs = process.communicate()

# Now you can write the output into a file, like so:

with open("path_to_log_file", "w") as log_file:
    f.write(outs)
```

Here's the docs for the `subproecss` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

I hope this answer was helpful :)